# Custom cursor around all instances of text in an application, without using <span>?

Tags: css, cursor

I am adding custom cursors to one of my web applications and I don't want the pointer cursor for everything. When you hover over text, your web browser will change to the text cursor, so I want a custom text cursor in my application as well.

You can change the cursor for text only using something like

```
<span class="curText">This is some text</span>

.curText { cursor: url(textcursor.cur), auto; }
```

I was hoping there was some easier way, even if it's a little "hacky", even if it involves both CSS and/or JavaScript, of selecting all text in an application. Otherwise, I will have to remember to add the  around any text that I want the text cursor for. This is certainly doable, though I am hoping there is an easier way.

Comment: @BoltClock The problem with that is that the text cursor will be over everything. My desired effect is to have it only over the text.

Comment: could you possibly just use `p, h1, h2, h3, h4 { cursor: url(textcursor.cur), auto; }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would *not* want to use the `<span>` tag, because its purpose is pretty much exactly right for you. There's no other pure CSS way that I know of to solve your problem. I'm sure you could hack it in jQuery (maybe using the `:parent` and/or `:empty` selectors, but that would be so much messier I don't really want to lead you in that direction...), but I'd say do it right and use `span`, especially if it's "certainly doable".

You don't have to apply your `curText` class to your spans, you could just add declarations for `p span,div span,li span` etc. since you want the style to apply accross the board and not just to specific spans

Comment: I've been researching literally everything about cursors for the last 3-4 hours or so and I think you are right. I was hoping for some easy CSS selector like `body::text` but unfortunately nothing like that exists so what you say is the next best thing. I have to edit my application and add the <span> tag wherever there is text. It is more tedious than I had hoped but so be it. I'm choosing this as the best answer. Thanks.